# Comparing the ckeditor value with the same value stored in the database by js in .Net6?

Tags: jquery, .net-6.0, ckeditor4.x

I saved the ckeditor value in the database, now in the edit section I called the same in the ckeditor,I want to compare that the value in the ckeditor field is the same as the value already recorded,

model code :

```
const modelCourseDescriptionValue = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(Model.Description))');
```

ckeditor:

```
let description = document.getElementById('Description').value;
if(modelCourseDescriptionValue == JSON.stringify(description)){
   alert("is Same")
}
```

If there is one line, the comparison is done correctly, but if there are several lines, it gives the following error...,

[image]

Is this method correct or not? What is the best way for this comparison?